# Use multiple controllers for Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a relatively simple personal project and have decided that using STI should work well for my needs. This is my first time using STI though, and I was wondering if it is advisable to use a separate controller for each model that is inheriting from the parent model?

I have a feeling the answer will depend on the use case, so what questions should I be asking myself in order to come to a conclusion of using separate controllers or just using one controller?

Comment: Decided? I would suggest avoiding STI as much as possible as it gets complicated sooner than later if you could share what derived you from coming to this conclusion then probably we could help much better. Also, please post some examples/code to work with.

Comment: I have done it both ways, and have found reasons to curse myself later in each case. I would stick with separate controllers and leverage controller concerns to keep dry at controller level.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers provide an "interface" for the external world to access. So it should match the access required.

An example of single controller (for user administration) would be for a parent User model with child models Teacher, Student, Admin. In this case, all 3 children will probably do CRUD the same way, with slightly different views, so a single controller will work.

If you have to start writing a few `if this_model ...` statements in the controller actions, consider using separate controllers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same hierarchy you have for STI models while defining the controllers.

Let's say you have `users` table with `User` ActiveRecord model representing it with STI models: `Admin` (type: 'Admin') and `Member` (type: 'Member'). Try this:

**models:**

```
app/models
├── user.rb
├── admin.rb
└── member.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Admin < User
end

class Member < User
end
```

**controllers:**

```
app/controllers
├── users_controller.rb
├── admins_controller.rb
└── members_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
end

class AdminsController < UsersController
end

class MembersController < UsersController
end
```